Conjugate element in A5 from the perspective of symmetry of dodecahedron
Learn from the lecture on symmetries of dodecahedron that rotations fixing the same pair of opposite vertices are conjugate elements of each other. Say rotations fixing 2 vertices A and B, name the 120 degree rotation g and 240 degree rotation h, why g and h is conjugate to each other? I can see the actions take vertex A to vertex B, and once A and B switched, g becomes h, but I can not see that action is conjugate. Can anyone help on this?

If $a$ denotes some symmetry which swaps $A$ and $B$, what is $aga^{-1}$?

I seem to have problem to visualize it, perhaps I’d better to buy a dodecahedron model to visualize it
